# R Code for removing values within a group

Tags: r, dataframe, data-management

I am working with data similar to the data below:

```
ID <- seq(1,10,1)
Letter <- c("A", "B", "C","C", "C", "D", "D", "E","F", "F")
df<- data.frame(ID, Letter)
```

```
   ID Letter
1   1      A
2   2      B
3   3      C
4   4      C
5   5      C
6   6      D
7   7      D
8   8      E
9   9      F
10 10      F
```

Looking specifically at the `Letter` column, I want to subset the data such that the `Letter` column only includes the `ID` value 4. But I want to keep all other values as well. So the data looks like:

```
   ID Letter
1   1      A
2   2      B
4   4      C
6   6      D
7   7      D
8   8      E
9   9      F
10 10      F
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R option

```
subset(df,ave(ID==4,Letter,FUN = function(x) Negate(any)(x)|x))
```

giving

```
   ID Letter
1   1      A
2   2      B
4   4      C
6   6      D
7   7      D
8   8      E
9   9      F
10 10      F
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do a group by operation i.e. grouping by 'Letter', `if` there is `any` 'ID' having 4, just get the logical vector based on that comparison or `else` return everything (`TRUE`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(Letter) %>%
     filter(if(any(ID == 4)) ID == 4 else TRUE)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   Letter [6]
#     ID Letter
#  <dbl> <chr> 
#1     1 A     
#2     2 B     
#3     4 C     
#4     6 D     
#5     7 D     
#6     8 E     
#7     9 F     
#8    10 F
```

---

Or another option without using a grouping would be

```
df %>%
   filter(Letter %in% setdiff(Letter, unique(Letter[ID == 4]))|ID == 4)
#  ID Letter
#1  1      A
#2  2      B
#3  4      C
#4  6      D
#5  7      D
#6  8      E
#7  9      F
#8 10      F
```

and its corresponding implementation in `base R`

```
subset(df, Letter %in% setdiff(Letter, unique(Letter[ID == 4]))|ID == 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `subset` `ID = 4` or all other values where `Letter` is different than the values in `ID = 4`.

```
subset(df, ID == 4 | !Letter %in% Letter[ID == 4])

#   ID Letter
#1   1      A
#2   2      B
#4   4      C
#6   6      D
#7   7      D
#8   8      E
#9   9      F
#10 10      F
```

This can also be written in `dplyr` as :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(ID == 4 | !Letter %in% Letter[ID == 4])
```